# Class inheritance python

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-django-storages

In the case creating a model, for example
class Student(models.Model)
name=models.charfield(),roll=models.integerfield()

similarly,
In the case creating a form, class newform(forms.Form)
name=forms.charfield(),roll=forms.integerfield()

similarly,
In the case creating a serializer, class serial(serializers.Serializer)
name=serializers.charfield(),roll=serializers.integerfield()

I understood that in each classes,a base class is inherited but i am confused that if different objects of different classes are created inside a class in each scenario then what is the meaning of inheriting models.model, forms.Form,serializers.Serializer what these inherited classes do?

Comment: You inherit their methods so you don't have to re-type them. Do you want an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django uses inheritance as well as object composition which are techniques of OOP for reusability.

Let us take your first class as example (I have only kept one field for simplicity):

```
Student(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

[Inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)):

The first line `Student(model.Model):` does inheritance by inheriting from `Model` class using which you are getting methods like `save()`, `delete()`, `clean_fields` e.t.c. Now your `Student` class can reuse those methods.

[Composition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)

The second line `name = models.CharField(max_length=100)` does object composition by creating object namely `name` of class `CharField` using which you get methods like `check`, `get_internal_type` e.t.c.

All of those Inbuilt classes (`Model`, `CharField` e.t.c) are defined in file namely `models.py` so when you do `models.Model` you are getting `Model` class from file `models.py` and `models.CharField` gives you `CharField` class from same file.

Answer (score 1):

By inheriting from other classes, you have access to their methods;

```
Class A(object): 
    def _print(self): 
        print('Class A') 

Class B(A): 
    def other_print(self): 
        print('Class B')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a, b = A(), B() 

    a._print()

    b._print()
    b.other_print()
```

When inheriting from model, forms, etc... You inherit from an object that is already integrated in the framework and thus has specific methods to work with the framework. For example the model will be registered to the database, the form 'knows' how to render properly, etc...

When you inherit from these classes, you already have an pre-built object with all these methods.

Comment: so these inherited classes do have some methods which are initiated automatically, right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In python when you need to be sure of the order of instantiation (for multiple inheritance) use `super(ClassToInstanciate, self).__init__(*args)` otherwise it should be handled automatically.